# How to know when touch has slid over from one div to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I'm working on a mobile app using jquery and need the user to be able to touch and hold on one div, then slide over to another div. I can't figure out how to make the second div register that the touch is now over it.

So for example when someone touches and holds div 4 and then slides into div 1, 3, 5 or 7 I want to be able to know which div they slid into and change things about that div.

here's a fiddle of what I have so far:
https://jsfiddle.net/hedonicmania/wuqa7a9y/4/

here's the code of what I have so far:

html:

```
<div class="game-container">
    <div class="game-square" id="0" ></div>
    <div class="game-square" id="1" ></div>
    <div class="game-square" id="2" ></div>
    <div class="game-square" id="3" ></div>
    <div class="game-square" id="4" ></div>
    <div class="game-square" id="5" ></div>
    <div class="game-square" id="6" ></div>
    <div class="game-square" id="7" ></div>
    <div class="game-square" id="8" ></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.game-container {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}
.game-square {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    /* inside border */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 1px solid #222;
    position: relative;
}
```

js:

```
var divs = $('.game-square');

$('.game-square').bind('touchstart', function(){    
    var thisDiv = document.getElementById($(this).attr('id'));

    thisDiv.style.backgroundColor = '#FFB395';
});

$('.game-square').bind('touchend', function(){
    var thisDiv = document.getElementById($(this).attr('id'));

    thisDiv.style.backgroundColor = '#ADE8AF';
});
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: With the `touchmove` event.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using flag on to check if the user is sliding the `game-square`. You can see the implementation on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wuqa7a9y/2/)